# How to show login screen only for the first time when app launches

Tags: ios, ipad, launching-application

I want to launch the login screen when first time app launches other wise app work simple but problem is that again again it goes to login screen.

here is the code which i am using in didFininsh

I want the user show go to login screen first time only and next time it should show splitViewController

```
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstLaunch",nil]];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {



    [self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];

    LoginViewController *targetController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;


    [self.splitViewController presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

else {


    [self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];

}


// my comment[window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
```

Comment: check out i think you have to written that code into viewwillappear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this...

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

    [self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];

    LoginViewController *targetController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;


    [self.splitViewController presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

else {


    [self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];

}
```

Comment: thanks it works but i want that when user enter user Name it commes in appDelegate.userName so how may i store it in NSUserDefaults so next time it is open app it should value in userName

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

Comment: after successful login there u just set the user defaults

Comment: mean i may set USerDefaults in LoginViewController

Comment: Yes. After successful login & remove that code from app delegate.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

Comment: i did not get after successful login  how will i remove this code what if app is installed on new device then how will it show login there for first time

Comment: User Default is stored in device only

Comment: yes but why to remove code after successful login and i have added code for UserDefaults how to assign those values to appDelegates

Comment: PUT THAT CODE AFTER SUCCESSFUL LOGIN AND REMOVE THE SAME FROM APP DELEGATE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32804/discussion-between-codesen-and-jaw-ali)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show only one time you Login Screen then you need to help of Database.

I give simple example of how to work with database table.

Suppose your You have Table name is  **"Login"**

add **Login** Table in 4 field

> id - auto-inc.
>   username - TEXT;
>   password - TEXT;
>   status - TEXT, default 0;

Take two ViewController

1) LoginViewController
2) HomeViewController

And in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

     /// here you need to get status from "Login" table 

     if (status == 0)
     {
        /// code of initialize LoginViewController
       self.window.rootViewController = self.LoginViewController;
     }
     else if (status == 1)
     {
          /// code of initialize HomeViewController
       self.window.rootViewController = self.HomeViewController;     
     }
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In above code, When you start you app. first time at that time check condition of **status** from **Login** table.

first time you got **status = 0** because we put default value of status is **0** so here,

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.LoginViewController;
```

At that time you enter userName and Password to your Login Screen.
after entered username and password you click on Login Button at That time you also need to fire Query of update **status** of you **'Login'** table is **1**

And when again you star your application at that time you ger **status is 1** so,

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.HomeViewController;
```

So, you can not display your login screen again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {



[self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
LoginViewController *targetController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;


[self.splitViewController presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

else {


[self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];

}


// my comment[window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the viewDidAppear method inside the Controller that needs to be skipped and then in the viewDidAppear method, do a segue to the view you want to send the user to, something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  //if user is already logged in then skip to welcome view
  //implement your login method here

  if ([self isUserLoggedIn]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeTo" sender:self];
  }

}
```

for ios7